# UIImage Crop Out Transparent Pixels

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics, crop

**I need help to create perfect clear image after cropping transparent pixel from UIImage using swift 4.**

> I want to create image with remove transparent color, So for that i
> have used below code.  But it blur image with small small square
> rectangles appears.

## Using of below code

```
let imageCroppedBg = imgWithClearBackgroung!.cropAlpha()


//UIImage extension
extension UIImage {
    func cropAlpha() -> UIImage {
        
        let cgImage = self.cgImage!;
        
        let width = cgImage.width
        let height = cgImage.height
        
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bytesPerPixel:Int = 4
        let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
        let bitsPerComponent = 8
        let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
        
        guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo),
            let ptr = context.data?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else {
                return self
        }
        
        context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        
        var minX = width
        var minY = height
        var maxX: Int = 0
        var maxY: Int = 0
        
        for x in 1 ..< width {
            for y in 1 ..< height {
                
                let i = bytesPerRow * Int(y) + bytesPerPixel * Int(x)
                let a = CGFloat(ptr[i + 3]) / 255.0
                
                if(a>0) {
                    if (x < minX) { minX = x };
                    if (x > maxX) { maxX = x };
                    if (y < minY) { minY = y};
                    if (y > maxY) { maxY = y};
                }
            }
        }
        
        let rect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(minX),y: CGFloat(minY), width: CGFloat(maxX-minX), height: CGFloat(maxY-minY))
        let imageScale:CGFloat = self.scale
        let croppedImage =  self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!
        let ret = UIImage(cgImage: croppedImage, scale: imageScale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        
        return ret;
    }
}
```

[image: Output blurred & small square in small]

[image: Image with Alpha/transparent pixel]

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, can you post an example of an UIImage that has transparent pixels? Where do you get that image? Do you create it programatically? And yes, I do see the edges which have some blur on them, I understand the issue, but I can't figure it out how can I reproduce the issue in order to tell exactly what's going on.

Comment: @MihaiErős, I have added transparent image also, for your reference.

Comment: I see that the image before "cropping" has those squares on borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking that the alpha component is just > zero maybe not enough in this line:

```
if(a>0) {
    if (x < minX) { minX = x }
    if (x > maxX) { maxX = x }
    if (y < minY) { minY = y }
    if (y > maxY) { maxY = y }
}
```

Maybe you could make the threshold higher : `if(a > 0.5)` or even higher. `if (a == 1)` would be the limit and it would guarantee that there is no transparency at all.

If you'd like to have the `imageCroppedBg` with the same size of  `imgWithClearBackgroung`, then set the content mode of the `UIImageView` containing `imgWithClearBackgroung` to `.scaleAspectFit`:

```
let imageCroppedBg = imgWithClearBackgroung.cropAlpha()
imageView.image = imageCroppedBg
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

For more on content modes, have a look [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/).

**P.S:** In Swift the `;` is not necessary at the end of the line.

Comment: Noted, Removed ';' from end of line, And i have also tried 0.5 but not works well, just minor change. Thank you for answer, DO you have any other idea or detail answer? Thank you in advance,

Comment: @Mehul if you inspect the png file that you've provided in Photoshop, you're going to see that the opacity of the extra pixels is 0.77. So The treshhold should be adjusted. In the extreme case you could require an alpha `a == 1`

Comment: Sure and thanks, I will check and let you know soon. :-)

Comment: Yes it works, but Image stretch. Image try to fit in original width & height, so output image will be looks like stretched. Can you please help me to get height & width of output image, So we will get perfect image after removing alpha pixel.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mehul could you please edit your question with your current results?

Comment: Yes i will update, but my-iPhone is water damaged. I will update soon brother.