# Calculate the correct with of UIImage using scale factor

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, scale

I'm trying to figure out with creates a bitmap-based graphics context with the specified options.

The idea is to save/redraw the existing image, using the scaleFactor because the **UIImageView** has content mode as aspectFit.

The problem is that after using the scale factor, the left margin of saved image has an empty space, and I cannot understand properly what I'm doing wrong with it.

Please see attached documents and if possible give me some hints!

Thank you in advance!

Pease & Love!

PS: Method and screenshot attached:

```
extension UIImageView {
  var mergedToImage: UIImage? {
    guard let originalImage = image else { return nil }
    let scaleFactor = CGFloat(max(originalImage.size.width / bounds.size.width,
                                  originalImage.size.height / bounds.size.height))
    
    let width = originalImage.size.width / scaleFactor
    let height = originalImage.size.height / scaleFactor
    
    let newSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize.size, false, 0.0)
    
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    return image
  }
}
```

[image: Original image]
[image: Rendered image]

**Working version here:**
Updated, thanks @Raja for the provided answer:

extension UIImageView {
var mergedToImage: UIImage? {

```
    guard let originalImage = image else { return nil }
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, false, originalImage.scale)
    
    guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    
    currentContext.scaleBy(
        x: originalImage.size.width / self.bounds.size.width,
        y: originalImage.size.height / self.bounds.size.height)
    
    layer.render(in: currentContext)
    
    let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return finalImage
}
```

}

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
// Don't forget to add this:
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let mainImageFrame = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: self.imageView.image?.size ?? .zero, insideRect: imageContainerView.frame)
        
        self.imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (imageContainerView.frame.size.width / 2) - (mainImageFrame.width / 2), y: (imageContainerView.frame.size.height / 2) - (mainImageFrame.height / 2)), size: mainImageFrame.size)
    }
```

Comment: You want same size output which is input image size. Right?

Comment: You could try `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize.size, false, 1.0)`, otherwise your scale factor would be 2.

Comment: @divanov42, thank you for your reply. I tried both option, doesn't work, the left margin still have that empty space.

Comment: @RajaKishan, yes, you're right.

Comment: have you draw anything on image? I mean any masking process there?

Comment: Yes, I'm drawing that aliens dude. But that doesn't affect the entire logic. I removed him but the error still here.

Comment: On iPad it's very bad. There's more space than on iPhone...
https://i.ibb.co/VtCccXY/Screen-Shot-2020-12-13-at-03-36-32.png

Comment: I just did one more try using this cropAlpha() method from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927700/uiimage-crop-out-transparent-pixels

  private func merge(imageView: UIImageView) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
      imageView.layer.render(in: context)
      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      return image
    }
    
    return nil
  }

How to use:

let image = merge(imageView: imageView)?.cropAlpha()

Answer (score 2):

Add scale in current context and pass image size in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions.

```
extension UIImageView {
    var mergedToImage: UIImage? {
        
        guard let originalImage = image else { return nil }
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, false, originalImage.scale)
        
        guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        
        currentContext.scaleBy(
            x: originalImage.size.width / self.bounds.size.width,
            y: originalImage.size.height / self.bounds.size.height)
        
        layer.render(in: currentContext)
        
        let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return finalImage
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

As per the provided demo, the image view is directly set. So first, add the image view inside the one UIView and set the image view frame according to image size. For finding the image display frame, use AVMakeRect. So final, your view controller file looks like this.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var eifellImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var imageContainerView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        eifellImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let mainImageFrame = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: self.eifellImageView.image?.size ?? .zero, insideRect: imageContainerView.frame)
        
        self.eifellImageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (imageContainerView.frame.size.width / 2) - (mainImageFrame.width / 2), y: (imageContainerView.frame.size.height / 2) - (mainImageFrame.height / 2)), size: mainImageFrame.size)
    }
    
    @IBAction private func onShareAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self.eifellImageView.mergedToImage as Any], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. But this didn't solve the situation, please see screenshot.

https://i.ibb.co/7J7sf2Z/Screen-Shot-2020-12-13-at-15-28-06.png

Comment: It’s working fine in my system and I also checked with masking process. Have you do anything with image view ?

Comment: I didn't do anything else with the image, but your solution doesn't work for my case.

Comment: If you're correct @raja kishan, please share a video demo how it works on your part with this image.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/g3fgqwg/1024px-Tour-Eiffel-Wikimedia-Commons.jpg

Comment: Can you do one thing print image size before mergedToImage and after mergedToImage because I have passed the same size image as input size so, there is no chance for change image and I suggest you check the image with a double-tap and open image.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you please check?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried, the image size is correct, but the empty space, around 20px still on both sides, please try the same image in landscape orientation.

Comment: Done. Getting the correct image without any extra empty space in landscape orientation. Can you please upload the code demo project on GitHub and share a link here so I can trace it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upload it on git, but please access the google drive shared link here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T1PRqj6LsjzMW-dmFMgwBcWK6YBP4wJX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If possible, please register a video how it works on your side, because on my side, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Why do you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true if we are working via storyboard?

Comment: Because I’m setting frame from iOS 13 frame will work after I set to true. Also one note when you add image view inside the view don’t give any constraint. It will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225997/discussion-between-raja-kishan-and-mihail-salari).

Comment: I noticed that inside of imageContainerView can use the view itself, right?

Comment: Yes, Use container view for feature implementation. If you use main view the image size considering according to view.